# Localizing DevExpress

Tags: delphi, localization, devexpress

Here in Denmark I am working on creating an app using DevExpress.
But I need to localize the DevExpress controls to speak Danish. But before I go to work and do the translation my self, I was wondering if someone already have done it.
I am using the cxLocalizerEditor to create the .ini file with the translation.

Does a Danish translation already exist?

Anyone got the localizing of Custom Resource Strings to work? I can't get it to work.

- Edited post to add sample code that I talk about later.

The example from the help is like following. But I can't get that to work at all.
    uses
      cxLocalization, dxCore, cxClasses, ;

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm, IdxLocalizerListener)
  cxLocalizer1: TcxLocalizer;
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
// ...
  public
    procedure TranslationChanged;
  end;
// ...

procedure TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  dxResourceStringsRepository.AddListener(Self);
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

procedure TForm1.Destroy;
begin
  dxResourceStringsRepository.RemoveListener(Self);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.TranslationChanged;
begin
  Caption := cxGetResourceString(@sAppName);
  // ...
end;
```

But what I can get to work is: (cxLanguage is the unit I created with custom resourcestrings using the Localizer UI and @sHpDbSettingsCaption is just a random resourcestring)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  cxLocalization, dxCore, cxClasses, cxLanguage,
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm, IdxLocalizerListener)
  procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
    procedure TranslationChanged;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TranslationChanged;
end;

procedure TForm1.TranslationChanged;
begin
  Caption := cxGetResourceString(@sHpDbSettingsCaption);
end;


end.
```

Comment: You might want to check [The collection of localized DevExpress assemblies](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A421.aspx)

Comment: @Nikola: The page you linked to is about .NET products. The OP should look at [How to localize VCL components](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18138.aspx).

Comment: @UlrichGerhardt Thanks. I was totally oblivious to `delphi` tag.

Comment: @OZ8HP, if you don't find anything for cxLocalizer, you might have better luck with cxIntl which has been around for some time. You probably can convert a cxIntl.ini for cxLocalizer.

Comment: @UlrichGerhardt: I have seen taht link earlier and found no Danish language. 
As far as I can figure out the cxIntl is totaly different approach. And I can't find any info about it that is newer than 2008

Comment: More information about what isn't working would be good, since nobody has a danish translation for you. "I can't get it to work" is too vague to be answerable. So "no, there is no danish one yet" is the only real answer possible.

Answer (score 4):

I did't use the cxLocalizerEditor but for ResourceString I made a constant unit to translate with cxSetResourceString and it works.

```
unit craDevExpressConsts;

interface

uses
  Classes,
  cxClasses,
  sysutils;

//GetDevExpressResourceString changed in ChangeResourceStrings
procedure ChangeResourceStrings;    
 implementation

uses
  cxFilterConsts,
  cxFilterControlStrs,
  cxEditConsts,
  cxGridStrs;

procedure ChangeResourceStrings;      
begin
  //================================
  // cxFilterControlStrs
  //================================
  // cxFilterBoolOperator
  cxSetResourceString(@cxSFilterBoolOperatorAnd, 'EN');
  cxSetResourceString(@cxSFilterBoolOperatorOr, 'OF');
  cxSetResourceString(@cxSFilterBoolOperatorNotAnd, 'NIET EN'); // not all
  cxSetResourceString(@cxSFilterBoolOperatorNotOr, 'NIET OF'); // not any
  cxSetResourceString(@cxSFilterFooterAddCondition, 'Selectie Toevoegen');


  //================================
  // cxEditConsts
  //================================
  // Invalid input value. Use escape key to abandon changes.
  cxSetResourceString(@cxSEditValidateErrorText, 'Ongeldige invoer waarde. Gebruik escape toets om wijzigingen te annuleren.');

  // Date
  cxSetResourceString(@cxSDatePopupClear, 'Ledigen'); // Clear
  cxSetResourceString(@cxSDatePopupNow, 'Nu'); // Now
  cxSetResourceString(@cxSDatePopupOK, 'Ok'); // OK
  cxSetResourceString(@cxSDatePopupToday, 'Vandaag'); // Today
  cxSetResourceString(@cxSDateError, 'Ongeldige Datum'); // Invalid Date

  ...

 end;

end.
```

Comment: But that's not Danish, is it? :-)

Comment: No, i did the translation manually in my unit because I just use Dutch in my application. When i start my application i just call craDevExpressConsts.GetDevExpressResourceString and all the resourcestrings from devexpress components are translated in Dutch. To translate english to dutch i use the google translation to help me.

Comment: Code review; Why is something that Sets resource string called GetResourceString?  Terrible name!  `ChangeResourceStrings` or anything other than `Get`!

Comment: @Warren P: Thanks for your advice. I change the name

Answer (score 3):

VCL localizations exist for Dutch, German and Italian [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18138.aspx).  I don't know of anything available in Danish.

Regarding the localization of Custom Resource Strings, you have not been clear enough about your exact problem, but there are several related issues in the support center:

[cxLocalizerEditor - Make created custom resource units compilable with the {$TYPEDADDRESS ON} compiler directive](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S138666.aspx)

[TcxLocalizer - Add the capability to create multiple custom products](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q271423.aspx)

If none of those help, I suggest you open a new question on the DevExpress support forums.

Comment: I haven't been able to locate any either, so I am going to make my own (then the spelling errors will be on my self :-) )
Regarding the custom resource strings then my problem is that the example that is in the manual I can't get running. And I haven't been able to locate any samples on the net.
The writing and translating of the resourcestrings is no problem.

Comment: Can you post more about the one you can't get running?  I am assuming you must build a resource BPL and register it somehow to make this work?

Comment: @Warren P:  it is the example from the manual I have been trying to get to work. I haven't got the manual with me here at the moment, but I will see if I can post some info later this day (it is 6 am here in Denmark now)

Answer (score -1):

1- create localizer classfor each control

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Localization;


 using System;    
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    class cls_GridLocalizer : GridLocalizer
        {
 public override string Language { get { return "Arabic"; } }
        public override string GetLocalizedString(GridStringId id)
        {
            string ret = "";
            switch (id)
            {
                case GridStringId.MenuColumnSortAscending: return "فرز تصاعدي";
                case GridStringId.MenuColumnSortDescending: return "فرز تنازلي";
                case GridStringId.MenuColumnClearSorting: return "الغاء 

الفرز";
                    case GridStringId.MenuColumnGroup: return "تجميع حسب هذا العمود";
.
.
.
.
  default:
                    ret = base.GetLocalizedString(id);

                    break;
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

2- call the class from the form containing the grid:

```
GridLocalizer.Active = new cls_GridLocalizer();
```

3- Enjoy

[this is arabic grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiApX.png)